# Word that means 'an unknown phenomenon or concept'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means 'an unknown phenomenon or concept'?
Is it really referred whit the one letter word 'X'?

Comment: thingamajig, whatsit

Comment: There are so many words. Have a look at [thing](http://thesaurus.com/browse/thing) in the thesaurus. Also [anything](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anything)

Comment: @GEdgar - Very intersting! Are they fractal words?

Comment: Can you give a lot more ...content to your questions? As is, it's difficult to know what you're thinking about. Give more details or an example.

Comment: whilst it remains unnamed, it may be unidentifiable.

Comment: @Mitch - Sorry, I confused 'any unnamed' with 'an unknown'. I have edited the question. Thanks to AndrewNimmo.

Comment: @Matt Эллен - Thanks for your answer, "thing" was perfect, but I confused unnamed with unknown.

Comment: I don't think this is constructive. OP clearly already knows **X** can be used in this way. If the unknown were a *number*, most people would call it **N**. If we knew *something* about it, we'd probably include that in the reference - an *unknown substance*, *unidentified force*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps consider *[conundrum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conundrum)* ("a difficult question or riddle"), *[enigma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enigma)* ("something puzzling, mysterious or inexplicable"), and *[mystery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mystery)* ("something secret or unexplainable; unknown").

Comment: Wow!!!!! Perfect!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean *an unknown*, the definition being:

1. an unknown person, quantity, or thing
2. (*Mathematics*) a variable, or the quantity it represents, the value of which is to be discovered by solving an equation; a variable in a conditional equation 3y = 4x + 5 is an equation in two unknowns

And, yes, *X* is often used to stand for an unknown.

Comment: oops! You are right, it is 'an unknown', not 'any unnamed'. I edited the question.